# How to generate positive private key from negrative private key for bitcoin in bitcoinj java or kotlin

Tags: java, cryptography, bitcoin, private-key, bitcoinj

I used -13 as private key in bitcoin but the private key is not valid. How can I get the positive private key from -13 or any other negative numbers using Bitcoinj or java and generate the same address?

```
val params = MainNetParams.get()

val b = BigInteger("-13")
val key = ECKey.fromPrivate(b, false)
println(LegacyAddress.fromKey(params, key)) // 122Vo9PeKd4j8zSGBeQHdmks6GnkpycXNz
```

Comment: Short answer: take the integer mod the order of group generated by the base point. Shorter answer: add `0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141` to it.

Comment: I don't get the math. Is it works for every negative number or just for -13? Can you please provide me with Java code?

Comment: First of all, it's completely unclear why you even have a negative number to begin with. But it works with any integer. `b.mod(new BigInteger("fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141", 16));` should give you the answer you seek, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: These magical constants are taken from the [SECG paper, section 2.7.1](https://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf)

Comment: A complete tutorial on elliptic curve cryptography is off-topic here. There are a lot of off-site tutorials available however.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I don't need to understand how the whole thing works for now, I'll come back to it when I'm good in math in the future. I just needed the code. You commented the answer, if you want you can post it so I can accept it.

Comment: These are operations on groups of numbers, which are mapped to ranges such as [0..N). So say that N = 17 then -13 is equivalent to 4 as `-13 mod 17 = 4`. James just posted a *slightly larger value* for N, specific to the curve seck256r1 used by BitCoin :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
b.mod(new BigInteger("115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337"))
```

Thanks to [president-james-k-polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/president-james-k-polk) in the comments